# Adding legends in a graphic

Tags: graphics, legending

I have several datasets,

[image]

and I successfully plotted them as points in a Graphic.
[image]

Then, how can I automatically create legends similar to PlotLegends with a color and a label for each dataset in the graphic? And the colors of the dataset points and the legend are consistent.

My goal is to plot a graph like this

[image]

Note: the intervals of x-value of my dataset are not equal, therefore I prefer not to use ListPlot.

Answer (score 1):

Extract your data using the form:

`mydata = (Point[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}] /. Point -> List)`

then `ListPlot[mydata, Legended->True]`

or

```
PlotLegends -> {"mydata1","mydata2"}
```

Comment: I prefer not to use ListPlot, though. Because the x-value of my dataset is not equally spaced.

Comment: `ListPlot` is perfect for datasets in which the $x$-axis data is not evenly distributed.

Comment: @chika, ListPlot nicely draws the data in form `{{x,y},...}`. The alignment of the legend inside the plot can be defined by `PlotLegends->Placed[LineLegend[{styles},{labels}],{position}]`

Comment: ListPlot really works! Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the documentation yet? [Here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListLinePlot.html?q=ListLinePlot).

This is an example there.

```
ListLinePlot[Table[Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 250]], {3}], 
Filling -> Axis, PlotLegends -> {"one", "two", "three"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fake datasets with a structure similar to the structure of your datasets:

```
SeedRandom[77]
graphics = Table[{PointSize[.001], 
 Point @ Transpose[{x = Sort @ RandomInteger[1000, 5000],
    RandomInteger[100] Sin[RandomReal[2 Pi] + RandomReal[2 Pi] x / 500] + 
      RandomReal[5, 5000]}]}, {5}];
g1 = Graphics[graphics, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
   ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True];
```

Colored version of the same:

```
colors = ColorData[63, "ColorList"][[;; Length@graphics]];
g2 = Graphics[Transpose[{colors, graphics}], 
   AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, ImageSize -> 400, Frame -> True]
```

using `LineLegend` and `Legended`

```
labels = Style["dataset " <> ToString[#], 16] & /@ Range[Length@graphics];
legend = LineLegend[Directive[#, AbsoluteThickness[5]] & /@ colors, labels];
Row[{g1, Legended[g2, Placed[legend, {Left, Top}]]}, Spacer[30]]
```

[image]